# How can I order a list of file paths (generated in Terminal) alphabetically?

Tags: macos, terminal, filepath

Lots of earlier questions about sorting file paths alphabetically, but I don't think any of them apply to my environment. Apologies if I'm wrong.

In Terminal on Mac, I'm currently using:

```
find [path to target folder] -type f > xlist.txt
```

to generate a list of file paths of video and subtitle files. What I am trying to produce is a list where the files are ordered as follows:

```
media_name S01E01.mkv
media_name S01E01.srt
media_name S01E02.mkv
media_name S01E02.srt
etc.
```

Currently the order seems more or less random.

Comment: if you jumble up the four lines you show and then run them through `sort` you get the order you want – which suggests these are not the actual lines you are sorting and something is missing from your question. If you edit your question to show (a snippet of) the contents of `xlist.txt`, how you are trying to sort them, what you are getting, and what you need then that will help people to help you. HTH

Comment: Thanks, yes, I assumed it should have been sorted alphabetically by default.  I added `| sort` to the command and it's now working.